# Mantain a class assigned by a hover event when the mouse is out

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I have a  section with 4 images inside. I want the hovered image to get a class, so it shows on top of the others. The reason I don't do this with CSS alone is that I want an image with that initial state, to be on top of others.

I am close with `mouseover` but I would like the class to remain in the last hovered image and not to disappear when the mouse is out, like a click event would do.

```
//Getting all the images in an Array:
const imagesArr = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll(".portfolio-single-image") );

//The container where the images are:
const mainGrid = document.querySelector("main");

//The event listener where the class is assigned and removed from the other elements:
mainGrid.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e){
    imagesArr.map((image)=> image.classList.remove("active-image") );
    e.target.classList.add("active-image");
});
```

The HTML:

```
<main>
    <img class="portfolio-single-image image1 active-image" src="X" alt="">
    <img class="portfolio-single-image image2" src="X" alt="">
    <img class="portfolio-single-image image3" src="X" alt="">
    <img class="portfolio-single-image image4" src="X" alt="">
</main>
```

Comment: "I want an image with that initial state, to be on top of others" why can't that be done with css?

Comment: Well explain how please. It can be done but then when you hover the other images that state has to be removed from the initial image.

Comment: Ah yeah for the removal you would need java script as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check if event target is image. adding/removing class works only when mouse is on an element with class `portfolio-single-image`.

```js
//Getting all the images in an Array:
const imagesArr = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll(".portfolio-single-image") );

//The container where the images are:
const mainGrid = document.querySelector("main");

//The event listener where the class is assigned and removed from the other elements:
mainGrid.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e){
 if(e.target.classList.contains('portfolio-single-image')){
    imagesArr.map((image)=> image.classList.remove("active-image") );
   
    e.target.classList.add("active-image");
    }
});
```

```css
.active-image {
border:1px solid red;
display:block;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <img class="portfolio-single-image image1 active-image" src="X" alt="">
    <img class="portfolio-single-image image2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="">
    <img class="portfolio-single-image image3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="">
    <img class="portfolio-single-image image4" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="">
</main>
```

Comment: That does work...Mind to explain why? Accepting when it allows me.

Answer (score 1):

See below. Adding an event listener to each image.

```js
//Getting all the images in an Array:
const images = [...document.querySelectorAll(".portfolio-single-image")];
//Listen for hover event for each image
images.map( image => image.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
    // Reset border
    images.map( image => image.classList.remove("active-image") );
    // Set border for correct image
    e.target.classList.add("active-image");
  })
);
```

```css
.active-image {
border: thin solid red;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <img class="portfolio-single-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="">
    <img class="portfolio-single-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="">
    <img class="portfolio-single-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="">
    <img class="portfolio-single-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="">
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `mousein()` and `mouseleave()` events instead of `mouseover()` - that gives you more flexibility and allows a "hoverstate" to remain when the mouse leaves again